# COALESCE command issue in Hive

Tags: select, hive, coalesce

I am trying to run a hive query using COALESCE function to create a view. But it is throwing error like 
cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'realvalue' in expression specification

The query is given below. Please help and mention what is wrong in this.

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS exampledb.`ara_service` AS
SELECT T1.EntityId, T1.entityname AS EntityName,
       T1.`xxx`,
       T1.`yyy`,
       COALESCE (T1.`aaa`, (SELECT `realvalue` FROM exampledb.`aba_service`
                            WHERE `id` = '333')) AS `CombinedValue`,
       T1.`ddd`,
       T1.`jjj`,
```

etc..

Please help. The error is in the usage of the select statement inside COALESCE . 
NoViableAltException(231@[435:1: precedenceEqualExpression : ( ( LPAREN precedenceBitwiseOrExpression COMMA )=> precedenceEqualExpressionMutiple | precedenceEqualExpressionSingle );])

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is a default value, you could do

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS exampledb.`ara_service` AS
SELECT T1.EntityId, T1.entityname AS EntityName,
       T1.`xxx`,
       T1.`yyy`,
       COALESCE (T1.`aaa`, def.`realvalue` ) AS `CombinedValue`,
       T1.`ddd`,
       T1.`jjj`,
FROM your_table T1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT `realvalue` 
    FROM exampledb.`aba_service` WHERE `id` = '333') def
```